# Android syntax error sqlite create table

Tags: android, sqlite

in my android app I am extending SQLiteOpenHelper to create a SQLite database.

Here is my **onCreate** method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE ? ( " + SuggestionColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)"; 
    String[] params = new String[]{SuggestionColumns.TABLE_NAME};
    database.execSQL(sql, params);
```

But LogCat prompts me the following error:

```
10-10 00:55:03.255: E/SQLiteLog(22311): (1) near "?": syntax error
10-10 00:59:20.605: W/SuggestionsAdapter(22311): Search suggestions query threw an exception.
10-10 00:59:20.605: W/SuggestionsAdapter(22311): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE ? ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
```

But if I substitute the placeholder with a string and call **execSql(sql);** it works.

So the question is: is it forbidden to use placeholders in CREATE TABLE statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders are limited to literals, such as the right-hand side of comparison statements in `WHERE` clauses, or the values to be inserted in an `INSERT` statement. Placeholders cannot be used for other portions of a SQL statement, such as table or column names.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. Is it present in the official documentation? I spent hours searching for it, with no result!

Comment: @user2340612: In the SQLite documentation for the C API, yes: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html